# Azure storage javascript client: how to track upload progress using Ionic/Angular?

Tags: angular, azure, ionic4, azure-blob-storage

Following this [guideline](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html), I want to track upload progress by getting the `progress` value to the DOM. I also want to print, say, 'done' in the DOM when the upload is finished. Is there a way to "subscribe" to SpeedSummary so I can get its progress value? Any other more recommended approach?

My code:

```js
      var finishedOrError = false;
      
      var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('input-data', filename, file, {blockSize : customBlockSize}, function(error, result, response) {
        finishedOrError = true;
        if (error) {
            // Upload blob failed
            alert('Problema: Volver a intentar o contactar al administrador');
        } else {
            // Upload successfully
            alert('Subida Exitosa');
            finish_upload();
            return result;
        }
      });
      
      speedSummary.on('progress', function () {
        var process = speedSummary.getCompletePercent();
        displayProcess(process);
      })

      var finish_upload = function(){
        //TODO set upload finish process
        //this.isUploading = false; DOESN'T WORK SINCE this is speedSummary in this context
      }
      var displayProcess = function(process){
        //TODO set progress indicator
      }
```

Note: I am aware of this [implementation](https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a)  but it gives me an error when implementing the `uploadFile` function. But more importantly I am looking for something more straigthforward to implement.

Note 2 : the error mentioned above is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 11, '(op1: UnaryFunction<Observable<number>, Observable<unknown>>, op2: UnaryFunction<Observable<unknown>, Observable<number>>): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<number>, Observable<unknown>>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me using my current library (please also note Jim Xu's answer for a solution with the latest library)

```
async uploadFileToAzure(file, filename, index){
    
        
    this.AStorage.getSAS(this.token, {"filename":filename}).subscribe(async sas=>{
      var self = this;
      this.sas = sas;
      var blobUri = 'https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/'; //actual blobUri goes here
      var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, this.sas["token"]);
      var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512; 
      blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;
  
      var finishedOrError = false;
      var self = this;
      var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('input-data', filename, file, {blockSize : customBlockSize}, function(error, result, response) {
        finishedOrError = true;
        if (error) {
            // Upload blob failed
            self.show_toast('Problema: Volver a intentar o contactar al administrador');
        } else {
            // Upload successfully
            self.show_toast('Subida Exitosa');
            finish_upload();

            return result;
        }
      });
      
      speedSummary.on('progress', function () {
        var process = speedSummary.getCompletePercent();
        displayProcess(process);
      })

      var finish_upload = function(){
        //TODO: set upload finish process
        
      }

      var file_to_process = this.files_to_process[index]
      var displayProcess = function(process){
        console.log('file_to_process', file_to_process)
        var s = document.getElementById(file_to_process)
        s.innerHTML = process;
        //var s = document.getElementById(progress_bars[index])
      }  
    });    
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to track upload progress when you upload blob in the angular application, you can use the new nodejs storage sdk `@azure/storage-blob` to implement it.

for example

1. Create an angular web app

```
ng new <appname>
```

2. install Azure storage SDk

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

2. Update app.component.html File

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
          <h1>Angular File Upload</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">Choose File</label>
        <input type="file"
               id="file"
               (change)="onFileChange($event)">
        <p> progress is = {{progress}} </p>
        <p>result: {{status}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

4. Add the following code in polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = require( 'process' );
(window as any).Buffer = require( 'buffer' ).Buffer;
```

5. Add the following code in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BlobServiceClient,AnonymousCredential,newPipeline } from '@azure/storage-blob';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web1';
  currentFile : File =null;
  onFileChange(event) {
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
    this.upload();
 }

 async upload(){
     const accountName ="andyprivate";
      const sasToken="";
      const containerName="test";
      
      const pipeline =newPipeline (new AnonymousCredential(),{
      retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
      userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
      keepAliveOptions: { enable: false}
      });

      const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                      pipeline  )
      const containerClient =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
                if(!containerClient.exists()){
                console.log("the container does not exit")
                await containerClient.create()

                }
     const client = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(this.currentFile.name)
     await client.uploadBrowserData(this.currentFile,{
                      blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                      concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
                      onProgress: (ev) => {
                        console.log(`you have upload ${ev.loadedBytes} bytes`);
                        this.progress= (ev.loadedBytes/this.currentFile.size)*100;
                    
                    },
                      blobHTTPHeaders :{blobContentType:this.currentFile.type}
       }).then(response =>{
                        console.log(response)
                        if(response.errorCode !=null){
                          console.log("failed")
                          this.status="fail";
                        }
                        this.status="done";
                      })
        
 }
}
```

6. Configure CORS in Azure storage account via Azure Portal. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services)

```
Allowed origins: *
Allowed verbs: DELETE,GET,HEAD,MERGE,POST,OPTIONS,PUT
Allowed headers: *
Exposed headers: *
Maximum age (seconds): 86400
```

7. Test
   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Jim Xu but i was looking for a solution using the library of the question. Was not able to check your answer although it seems correct.